# django: How do I hash a URL from the database object's primary key?

Tags: python, django, design-patterns, url, hash

I'm trying to generate URLs for my database objects. [I've read](http://agiliq.com/books/djangodesignpatterns/misc.html#do-not-use-primary-keys-in-urls) I should not use the primary key for URLs, and a stub is not a good option for this particular model. Based on the advice in that link, I played around with zlib.crc32() in a Python interpreter and found that values often return negative numbers which I don't want in my URLs. Is there a better hash I should be using to generate my URLs?

**UPDATE:** I ended up using the bitwise XOR masking method suggested by David below, and it works wonderfully. Thanks to everyone for your input.

Comment: Not quite what you asked for (and hence not an answer), but you might consider slug-ifying the title and using that. Basically you lower/scrub/reduce until it's legal, store it as a field in the object (indexed!), and then have a pattern in urls.py that matches it.

Comment: Check out the [urlauth](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-urlauth/0.1.8) app. It won't solve your needs, but you can take a look at how it composes the URLs, saves the keys into DB and validates the URLs back when they are requested.

Comment: @PeterRowell I would prefer to use a numeric value as these will probably not be accessed arbitrarily by URL.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, "don't use primary keys in URLs" is only a very weak guideline. *If* you are using incremental integer IDs *and* you don't want to reveal those numbers, then you could obfuscate them a little bit. For example, you could use: `masked_id = entity.id ^ 0xABCDEFAB` and `unmasked_id = masked_id ^ 0xABCDEFAB`.

Second, the article you linked to is *highly* suspicious. I would not trust it. First, CRC32 is a one-way hashing function: it's impossible (in general) to take a CRC32 hash and get back the string used to create that hash. You'll notice that he doesn't show you how to look up a `Customer` given the CRC32 of their `pk`. Second, the code in the article doesn't even make sense. The `zlib.crc32` function expects a byte string, while `Customer.id` will be an integer.

Third, be careful if you want to use a slug for a URL: if the slug changes, your URLs will also change. This may be okay, but it's something you'll need to consider.

Comment: `^ 0xABCDEFAB` is a nice solution. For anyone unsure what it's doing, that's the bitwise XOR operator.