# Django: hiding the primary key (pk) and using DetailView with get_queryset

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Following up on this thread: [django: How do I hash a URL from the database object's primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559935/django-how-do-i-hash-a-url-from-the-database-objects-primary-key), I would like to hide primary keys from users and use `Detailview` in my urlconf. I was able to accomplish this hiding using bitwise XOR for the most part (it worked in my view functions), until I got to the part where I had to "unmask" the masked primary key that was sent in the url to my subclass of `DetailView`.

How do I "unmask" my pk_masked named group before sending it to my `DetailViewFilteredOnUser(DetailView)` instance? Is there a way to send `mask_toggle(pk_unmasked)` to my call to DetailViewFilteredOnUser right in the urlconf? In searching for solutions, I found something about `pk_url_kward` in the Django documentation, but I couldn't get it to work and anyways I don't think that can help me perform operations on the primary key that DetailView operates on.

Here is my masking function:

```
def mask_toggle(number_to_mask_or_unmask):
    return int(number_to_mask_or_unmask) ^ settings.MASKING_KEY
```

My models are "pkgs" that contain "items":

```
class Pkg(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)
    tracking_number = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    pkg = models.ForeignKey(Pkg)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

Here is what is in my urls.py:

```
class ListViewFilteredOnUser(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Pkg.objects.order_by('-created_at').filter(user=self.request.user)

class DetailViewFilteredOnUser(DetailView):
    def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(DetailViewFilteredOnUser, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(user=self.request.user)

....

url(r'^(?P<pk_masked>\d+)/$',
    login_required(DetailViewFilteredOnUser.as_view( model=Pkg,
                        template_name='pkgs/detail.html'
                        )), 
    name='detail'),
```

So the problem is that if my named group in my urlconf is "pk", then a masked primary key (because the masked key is what is in the url) is sent to DetailView. If my named group in my urlconf is "pk_masked", then I need to do `pk=mask_toggle(pk_masked)` somewhere, and I can't figure out where or how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you need to override `get_object` (which makes `get_queryset` pretty much irrelevant, but you can still use it for clarity). Something like:

```
class DetailViewFilteredOnUser(DetailView):
    model = Pkg
    template_name = 'pkgs/detail.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(DetailViewFilteredOnUser, self).get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)
    def get_object(self):
        return self.get_queryset().get(pk=mask_toggle(self.kwargs.get("pk_masked"))
```

(Of course, don't forget to catch exceptions, I left that out for clarity and brevity.)

Comment: Hello Berislav, thanks so much for this - it works perfectly! It occurred to me that the bitwise-XOR "encryption" solution that I am using to mask the PK is probably easily breakable. I might try to use a different masking algorithm. If I do and it works, I'll post the solution here. Cheers,

Comment: I think it should be OK for all practical purposes, but you might wish to check out the `pycrypto` library.